# Share a service between two or more plugins

Tags: kuzzle

I need to share a payment service class between two (or more) plugins and am wondering if Kuzzle's Pipes are the best solution for that?

I made a poc which seems to work, nevertheless, I don't found any similar example on kuzzle's plugins (like for hooks with Kuzzle-plugin-logger)

What are the other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to share functionalities between plugins is to declare them as API actions.

You could expose your payment service features by creating a plugin named `payment` for example and declaring a [controller](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/plugins/guides/controllers/) inside.

```
this.controllers = {
  card: {
    pay: request => ...,
    fraudCheck: request => ...
  }
};
```

Then you can use the [embedded SDK](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/plugins/plugin-context/accessors/sdk/) to call those actions from another plugin. The request will be directly transmitted to Kuzzle without using the network.

```
this.context.accessors.sdk.query({
  controller: 'payment/card',
  action: pay,
  number: '...',
  ccv: 543,
  ...
});
```

Since Kuzzle rights are [whitelist based](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/essentials/security/#whitelist-strategy) so external users will not be able to call your actions unless you explicitly specify it in their roles.